# inserting data into multiple mySQL tables using flask with one query

Tags: python, mysql, flask, insert

I have two distinct tables in mySQL :

`'Books' ('id', 'title', 'author_id')`

and

`'Authors' ('id', 'author')`

Both id's are auto-increment and the tables have a one to many relationship with the foreign key `('author_id')` on `Books`.  My task is to enter a new author and book in one single swoop since data are coming via a POST method to these tables from the same form in HTML.

I have manually tried this on mySQL and it works great:

```
INSERT INTO authors (author, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES ('Gerald Durrell',NOW(),NOW());
INSERT INTO books (title, rating, created_at, updated_at, author_id)
VALUES ('Birds',5, NOW(),NOW(), LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

In my Flask app, I have the exact same query but the system gets mad and doesn't allow me to do it.

My models.py

```py
mysql = connectToMySQL('books')
query = 'INSERT INTO authors (author, created_at, updated_at) 
VALUES (%(author)s,NOW(),NOW()); INSERT INTO books
(title, created_at, updated_at, author_id) VALUES (% .
(title)s, NOW(),NOW(), LAST_INSERT_ID());'
data = {
    'author': request.form['author'],
    'title': request.form['title'],
}
mysql.query_db(query,data)
```

my html:

```html
<form action='/addbook' method='POST'>
   <label for='title'>Book Title:</label>
   <input type="text" name='title'>
   <p>Enter new author:</p>
   <input name='author' type="text">
   <input type='submit' value='Click to add book'>
</form>
```

The command works manually when I enter it in mySQL. But it crashes in Flask. I do know that the connection between mySQL and Flask app is good because I successfully entered users who have navigated to this 'Add book page'. 
This is the exact error message that pops up in my terminal:

> Something went wrong (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO books (title, rating, created_at, updated_at, author_id) VAL' at line 1")

The workaround is to incorporate author into the book table, but then I won't be able to iterate through authors in a different section of the app.

Comment: 9 out the 10 times a MySQL client in a programming lauguage does not support running multiple queries which are separated by a semicon (`;`) at once in one functions... Some times you need to set a flag to allow it..

Comment: I have tried both with and without semi-colon but no luck. I have also tried two separate queries, but then I get a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of struggle, it turns out that Flask does not do multiple queries. So I changed the program to have two different routes.

Route 1 : populate the author table with author fields. 
and then return a the id-value which flask does automatically anyway and put it in session.

Then route 2: populate the book table with the same form fields and also the author_id field from session.